# JMX - how to monitor remotely a cpu usage of an applicaiton

Tags: java, mule, monitoring, jmx

How to implement a Back-end JMX remote monitoring of the usage CPU of my API/Applications.

how would i monitor or put a specification of the application that i want to monitor?

example.

```
Host : serverhost.example.com
Port : 8088
API/Application : Google Chrome
Monitor : CPU = 35%
          Memory = 30%
```

Following is the code snippet

```
OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.cl‌​ass);
 System.out.println("CPU USAGE " + osBean.getProcessCpuLoad() * 100);
 System.out.println("CPU USAGE " + osBean.getSystemCpuLoad() * 100);
 System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
 System.out.println("MEMORY USAGE " + osBean.getCommittedVirtualMemorySize());
 System.out.println("MEMORY USAGE " + osBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize());
 System.out.println("MEMORY USAGE " + osBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize());
 System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Robert here's my code snippet. my question is how would i monitor or put a specification of the application that i want to monitor?

Comment: OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class); System.out.println("CPU USAGE " + osBean.getProcessCpuLoad() * 100);
  System.out.println("CPU USAGE " + osBean.getSystemCpuLoad()  * 100);
  System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
  System.out.println("MEMORY USAGE " + osBean.getCommittedVirtualMemorySize());
  System.out.println("MEMORY USAGE " + osBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize());
  System.out.println("MEMORY USAGE " + osBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize());
  System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Format your code as such (use the {} button or indent 4 spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Though it is possible to achieve the same with JMX, I found it much easier to use an adapter to get the matrices as JSON via a rest API.

I achieved the same functionality via [jolokia](https://jolokia.org/) which exposes the JMX endpoints as Rest endpoints.
Then I used MatrixBeat to get the matrices to push to ELK stack.

Instead of ELK, I found some other tools like [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) which also do the job well.